# Python, Rpi server status notifier

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

--First month in programming; be gentle with me--

I'm looking to build a short application using `python` to run on an `RPi`; the idea is to ping our company owned servers individually and eventually have them return as LED status lights. For now though; I would like it to broadcast a desktop notification to specific Macs on the same network.
I have 0 experience with python or programming general. Where should I start?

Answer (score 0):

For learning Python there are too many very good web ressources easily found on the net, so I don't mention them here. For your nice little project for the Raspi you should get familiar with the python module called RPi.GPIO. With it you can easily turn on & off your LEDs depending on the ping response of your company servers.